# how to SUM two different columns in two different table between two date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Below is my query:

`select sum(tableA.value)+sum(tableB.value1) ) 
from tableA,tableB 
where tableA.data between '2016-01-21' and '2016-03-09' 
and tableB.date2 between '2016-01-21' and '2016-03-09'`

But the results are wrong when number of rows are different.
Example **tableA.value = 2** and **tableB values are =3 and 5**  the **result =12**

This is wrong. The result  should have been 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with sumA as (
    select sum(tableA.value) value from tableA 
     where tableA.data between '2016-01-21' and '2016-03-09'
), sumB as (
    select sum(tableB.value) value from tableB 
     where tableB.date2 between '2016-01-21' and '2016-03-09'
)
select a.Value + b.Value from sumA, sumB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(A.value) OVER (PARTITION BY A.date order by A.date) + 
    SUM(B.value) OVER (PARTITION BY B.date order by B.date) 
FROM
(select value, date from tableA where date between '2016-01-21' and '2016-03-09')A --2, d1
CROSS JOIN 
(select value, date from tableB where date between '2016-01-21' and '2016-03-09')B --3,d2 and 5,d3
--Result of CROSS JOIN is below
--2,d1,3,d2
--2,d1,5,d3
-- which gives result as 
--2+8=10
```